# How to present actionController on iPad in the middle of the screen from tableView action?

Tags: swift

I know this has been asked before, but I can't find the correct solution.

I have a tableView UIContextualAction which calls an alertController. On the iPad I want it to appear center screen. The viewStack consist of a modally presented VC with a tableViewController.

**This displays the alert Controller at the tableViewRow**

```swift
let configureAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: nil) { [weak self] (action, view, isSuccess) in
                
let ac = UIAlertController(title: LocalizedString.titles.chooseInputMethod, message: LocalizedString.helpTexts.chooseInputMethodSerial, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
popoverController.sourceView = view
popoverController.sourceRect = view.bounds
```

**Trying to present it center screen**

```swift
popoverController.sourceView = self?.view
popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self?.view.bounds.midX, y: self?.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
```

Error: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

From earlier post, it seems like the last code has been correct for many others, but I still get a syntax error here.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how you get your `popoverController`, because you didn't show it clearly in code.
Here is a piece of code which works correctly for me:

```
let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Pop-up", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
let popoverController = ac.popoverPresentationController
popoverController?.sourceView = self.view
popoverController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Regarding the error that you get:

`Error: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments`

- I am not sure if it is related to this popoverController. Can you make a screenshot with the exact line of code where the error is being shown?

**EDIT**

```
let configureAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: nil) { [weak self] (action, view, isSuccess) in 
    guard let self = self else { return }

    //...other code that you have

    if let popoverController = ac.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverController.sourceView = self.view
        popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
    }
}
```

The reason why you have that error, is most probably because your `self` is weak, and thus, it returns an optional value for `x` and `y` parameters.
I included the `guard let self = self else { return }`, which will capture the self for the closure and hold a strong reference to it until your closure is finished executing.

Comment: Image uploaded :=)

Comment: @perage did it work? If yes, please mark the answer as correct. Thanks